# Error de visualización de inputs creados dinámicamente con jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

[image: inputs a añadir]

Puedo añadir y eliminar los inputs perfectamente, cada uno con su 'name[]' para posteriormente guardarlos en la base de datos. Pero al añadir los inputs, estos no se muestran correctamente. 
[image: error de visualización]
Cuando inspecciono los divs, veo que el primer div que se crea en la función envuelve a todo los inputs, incluyendo el principal que crea a los demás inputs. No estoy seguro cual sea el problema, ya que he intentado cambiando las clases de los inputs (class=row) a los que se van agregando, pero el resultado es peor.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append('<div><div class="col-third"><div class="input-group input-group-icon"><input type="text" name="nombre_pax_pref[]" placeholder="Nombre Pax" required/><div class="input-icon"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></div></div></div><div class="col-third"><select style="width: 29%; padding-right: 10px;float: left;" name="select" id="selectLg" class="form-control-lg form-control" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value"><option disabled selected>-ID-</option><option>RUT:&nbsp;</option><option>PAS:&nbsp;</option><option>DNI:&nbsp;</option></select><input style="width: 71%" type="text" placeholder="Nº" name="rut_pax[]"/></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg remove_field">-</button></div>'); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```css
.row {
    zoom: 1;
}
.row {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;

@media (min-width: 992px)
.col-lg-12 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;

.col-lg-12 {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 1px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}

.col-third {
    padding-right: 10px;
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333%;

.input-group-icon {
    position: relative;
}

.input-group {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    zoom: 1;
}
.input-group {
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-align: stretch;
    align-items: stretch;
    width: 100%;
}

.input-group-icon input {
    padding-left: 4.4em;
}

.input-group-icon .input-icon {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 3.4em;
    height: 3.4em;
    line-height: 3.4em;
    text-align: center;
    pointer-events: none;
}

input, textarea {
    border: none;
}
input, input[type="radio"] + label, input[type="checkbox"] + label:before, select option, select {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 1em;
    line-height: 1.4;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
    transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="input_fields_wrap">
        <div class="col-third">
          <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
            <input type="text" name="nombre_pax_pref[]" placeholder="Nombre Pax" required/>
            <div class="input-icon"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-third">
          <select name="select" id="selectLg" class="form-control-lg form-control" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
            <option disabled selected>-ID-</option>
            <option>RUT:&nbsp;</option>
            <option>PAS:&nbsp;</option>
            <option>DNI:&nbsp;</option>
          </select>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Nº" name="rut_pax[]"/>
        </div>
        <div class="col-third">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg add_field_button">+</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Deberías agregar los estilos de esa sección de tu código

Comment: Ya agregué los estilos.

Comment: Se sigue viendo sin estilos en el snippet, si usas librerías debes importarlas, revisa bien!

Answer (score 0):

tienes un `div` al inicio del codigo y te falta otro antes del  `div` al principio de `<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-lg remove_field">+</button></di>` del codigo javascript pero no es requerido puedes usar el metodo `before` y agregarle un `id="btn-add"`.

**ejemplo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('.col-third > select[id="selectLg"]').length < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        $("#btn-add").before('<div class="col-third"><div class="input-group input-group-icon"><input type="text" name="nombre_pax_pref[]" placeholder="Nombre Pax" required/><div class="input-icon"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></div></div></div><div class="col-third"><select style="width: 29%; padding-right: 10px;float: left;" name="select" id="selectLg" class="form-control-lg form-control" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value"><option disabled selected>-ID-</option><option>RUT:&nbsp;</option><option>PAS:&nbsp;</option><option>DNI:&nbsp;</option></select><input style="width: 71%" type="text" placeholder="Nº" name="rut_pax[]"/></div>'); //add input box
    }else{
        $("#btn-add").remove();
    }
});
});
```

```css
    .row {
        zoom: 1;
    }
    .row {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -15px;

    @media (min-width: 992px)
    .col-lg-12 {
        -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        max-width: 100%;

    .col-lg-12 {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
    }

    .col-third {
        padding-right: 10px;
        float: left;
        width: 33.33333333%;

    .input-group-icon {
        position: relative;
    }

    .input-group {
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        zoom: 1;
    }
    .input-group {
        position: relative;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-align: stretch;
        align-items: stretch;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .input-group-icon input {
        padding-left: 4.4em;
    }

    .input-group-icon .input-icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 3.4em;
        height: 3.4em;
        line-height: 3.4em;
        text-align: center;
        pointer-events: none;
    }

    input, textarea {
        border: none;
    }
    input, input[type="radio"] + label, input[type="checkbox"] + label:before, select option, select {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 1em;
        line-height: 1.4;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
        border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        border-radius: 3px;
        -webkit-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
        -moz-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
        -o-transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
        transition: 0.35s ease-in-out;
        transition: all 0.35s ease-in-out;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div style="padding: 0;"class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="input_fields_wrap">
            <div class="col-third">
              <div class="input-group input-group-icon">
                <input type="text" name="nombre_pax_pref[]" placeholder="Nombre Pax" required/>
                <div class="input-icon"><i class="fas fa-calendar-alt"></i></div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-third">
              <select style="width: 29%; padding-right: 10px;float: left;" name="select" id="selectLg" class="form-control-lg form-control" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value=this.value">
                <option disabled selected>-ID-</option>
                <option>RUT:&nbsp;</option>
                <option>PAS:&nbsp;</option>
                <option>DNI:&nbsp;</option>
              </select>
              <input style="width: 71%" type="text" placeholder="Nº" name="rut_pax[]"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-third" id="btn-add">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg add_field_button">+</button>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```